# Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int', using provider

Tags: flutter, null, integer, provider, flutter-provider

I am facing this issue while trying to save ID from article when user tap in order to save article and pass it into the favourite page. Every time I go to the favourite page i get this error message "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'".

Please, how can I solve it?

Article page where user tap to save article
[image]

Favourite page where articles have to show up
[image]

Main with change nofitier provider

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var data;
  var id;
  List<ArticleModel> allArticles = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<FavoriteProvider>(
            create: (context) => FavoriteProvider(allArticles),
            builder: (contex, _) {
              return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              /// Google Analytics
              navigatorObservers: [locator<AnalyticsService>().getAnalyticsObserve(),],
              theme: assoFacileNewsTheme,
              /// Routes
              initialRoute: "/splashScreen",
              routes: {
              /// Primary pages
              "/splashScreen":              (_) => SplashScreen(),
              "/onboardingScreens":         (_) => OnboardingScreens(),
              /// bottom navigation bar pages
              "/homepage":                  (_) => HomePage(),
              "/formazione":                (_) => FormazionePage(),
              "/favorite_articles":         (_) => FavoritePage(id: id,),
            },
         );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

ChangeNotifier page

```
class FavoriteProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<ArticleModel> _allArticles = [];
  final List<int> _favoriteArticleIds = [];
  List<int> get favoriteArticleIds => _favoriteArticleIds;
  int get favoriteCount => _favoriteArticleIds.length;
  FavoriteProvider(List<ArticleModel> allArticles) {allArticles.addAll(allArticles);}
  /// Function to check if an article is favorited
  bool isFavorite(int favoriteArticleIds) {return _favoriteArticleIds.contains(favoriteArticleIds);} // was articleId

  /// Function to add or remove an article from favorites
  void toggleFavorite(int favoriteArticleIds, context) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_favoriteArticleIds.contains(favoriteArticleIds)) {
      _favoriteArticleIds.remove(favoriteArticleIds);
      print("Removed $favoriteArticleIds from _favoriteArticleIds");
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(duration: Duration(seconds: 3),backgroundColor: Colors.white, content: Text("Articolo rimosso", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),);
    } else {
      _favoriteArticleIds.add(favoriteArticleIds);
      print("Saved $favoriteArticleIds to _favoriteArticleIds");
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(duration: Duration(seconds: 3),backgroundColor: Colors.white, content: Text("Articolo salvato", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Fetch favourite articles
  Future<List<ArticleModel>> fetchFavoriteArticles() async {
    final favoriteArticles = _allArticles.where((article) => _favoriteArticleIds.contains(article.id)).toList();
    print("Favorite Articles in fetchFavoriteArticles: ${favoriteArticles.length}");
    return favoriteArticles;
  }
}
```

The article page

```
class ArticlePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id; final String? urlImage; final String? title; final String? description; final dynamic data;
  const ArticlePage({Key? key, required this.data, required this.id, this.urlImage, this.title, this.description}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ArticlePageState createState() => _ArticlePageState(data, id, urlImage, title, description);
}

class _ArticlePageState extends State<ArticlePage> {
  int id;final urlImage;final title;final description;final data;
  late FavoriteProvider favoriteArticles;
  late bool _favoriteArticlesReady;
  late bool isFavorite = false;
  _ArticlePageState(this.data, this.id, this.urlImage, this.title, this.description,);

  /// Function to save and remove articles
  void btnFunction() {
    favoriteArticles.toggleFavorite(widget.id, context);
    setState(() {
      isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    favoriteArticles = Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(context, listen: false);
    isFavorite = favoriteArticles.isFavorite(widget.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Consumer<FavoriteProvider>(builder: (context, favoriteArticles, _) {
         return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leading: const PreviousBtn(),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                background: CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: data["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["link"],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset("assets/gif/shimmer.gif", fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset("assets/images/unloadedImage.png", width: 250, height: 250,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                Visibility(child: Text(data['id'].toString()), visible: false,),
                /// Favorite icon
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                  child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, bottom: 10.0,),
                      width: 35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), color: Colors.white,),
                      child:
                      IconButton(
                        icon: isFavorite
                            ? const Icon(Icons.bookmark_outlined, color: Color(0xFF0D47A1), size: 18,)
                            : const Icon(Icons.bookmark_outline_outlined, color: Color(0xFF0D47A1), size: 18,),
                        onPressed: btnFunction,
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
                /// Share article icon
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/images/share_icon.png',),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Share.share(data["link"], subject: "Leggi l'articolo di AssoFacile News $title",
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ], floating: true, expandedHeight: 320,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      /// Article title
                      Text(
                        data["title"]["rendered"].toString().replaceAll("<p>", "").replaceAll("&#8217;", "'").replaceAll("</p>", ""),
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "Raleway",),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 0),
                      /// Text content
                      HtmlWidget(
                        data['content']['rendered'].toString()
                            .replaceAll("<p>", "")
                            .replaceAll("&#8217;", "'")
                            .replaceAll("<img>", "")
                            .replaceAll("<div>", "<div>").replaceAll("</div>", "</div>")
                            .replaceAll("</p>", ""),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
         );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The favourite page where articles should appear

```
class FavoritePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id; final data;
  const FavoritePage({Key? key, this.data, required this.id}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _FavoritePageState createState() => _FavoritePageState();
}

class _FavoritePageState extends State<FavoritePage> {
  String title  = "Articoli Preferiti";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Favourite page article id: ${widget.id}");
    final importFavourites = Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(context, listen: false).fetchFavoriteArticles;
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavbarMenu(),
      appBar: CustomAppBar(leadingBtn: const DehazeIconBtn(), title: title,),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: importFavourites(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final favoriteArticlesData = snapshot.data as List<ArticleModel>;
              print("Favorite Articles Length: ${favoriteArticlesData.length}");
              if (favoriteArticlesData.isEmpty) {
                return const EmptyArticle();
              }
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: favoriteArticlesData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final article = favoriteArticlesData[index];
                  return Card(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    elevation: 5,
                    shadowColor: Colors.black26,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 190,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: Image(
                                image: AdvancedNetworkImage(
                                  article.urlImageSource ?? "", useDiskCache: true, cacheRule: const CacheRule(maxAge: Duration(days: 1)),
                                ), fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 16, bottom: 16),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          article.title?.replaceAll("&#8217;", "'").replaceAll("<p>", "").replaceAll("</p>", "") ?? "",
                                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontFamily: "Raleway",),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          maxLines: 2,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        final id = article.id;
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ArticlePage(data: article, id: id),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const EmptyArticle();
            }
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: would be great if u can create a gist for this secnario, would be easy to review the code to check where the issue lies in

Comment: I need that when goes to the article page and users tap on the bookmark icon to save the article on favourite page, the provider has to pass the article ID of the article dedicated into the favourite page in order to show it up. I just added more info

Comment: That error frequently happens when you've declared something as const that shouldn't be.  Typically, try deleting the previous const keyword from the point where the error is reported.

Comment: As you can see, there is not any const in the code !!!!!